# Turning string characters into nested array keys

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying figure out how to turn the non-zero characters of a string into nested array keys. For example, given `$id = '12430'` I would like to end up with `$tree[1][2][4][3]['id'] = '12430'`. I've tried several different unsuccessful approaches, the latest being:

```
$id = '12430';
$keys = str_split($id);

function addKey($keys, $id, $array = array())
{
    if ($keys[0] != '0')
    {
        $key = $keys[0];
        $array[$key] = array();

        array_shift($keys);

        addKey($keys, $id, $array[$key]);
    }
    else
    {
        $array['id'] = $id;

        return $array;
    }
}

$tree = addKey($keys, $id);
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is it even possible?

Comment: What is the pattern?  Why is the `0` ignored?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Because it's meaningless for my purposes. (I'm constructing a family tree.)

Comment: @AbraCadaver FYI, this particular ID identifies the person as the 3rd child of the 4th child of the 2nd child of the 1st generation couple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
class Tree {

    /**
     * @static
     * @access  private
     * @var     array
     */
    private static $aTree = array();

    /**
     * Add single key.
     * 
     * @static
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  $sString
     * @param   array   $aTree
     * @param   string  $sStoredString
     */
    public static function addKey($sString, array &$aTree = NULL, $sStoredString = NULL) {
        if($aTree === NULL) {
            $aTree = &static::$aTree;
        }

        if($sStoredString === NULL) {
            $sStoredString = $sString;
        }

        $sNewKey     = $sString[0];
        $sNewString  = substr($sString, 1);

        if(empty($sNewKey)) {
            $sNewString  = '';
            $aTmp        = &$aTree;
        } else {
            if(!isset($aTree[$sNewKey])) {
                $aTree[$sNewKey] = array();
            }

            $aTmp = &$aTree[$sNewKey];
        }

        if(!empty($sNewString)) {
            static::addKey($sNewString, $aTmp, $sStoredString);
        } else {
            if(!isset($aTmp['id'])) {
                $aTmp['id'] = $sStoredString;
            } else {
                $aTmp['id'] = array($aTmp['id'], $sStoredString);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add multiple keys.
     * 
     * @static
     * @access  public
     * @param   array   $aKeys
     */
    public static function addKeys(array $aKeys) {
        foreach($aKeys as $sKey) {
            static::addKey($sKey, static::$aTree, $sKey);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get whole tree.
     * 
     * @static
     * @access  public
     * @return  array
     */
    public static function getTree() {
        return static::$aTree;
    }

}
```

Example:

```
Tree::addKeys(array('12400', '12430', '233', '2010', '2011'));
Tree::addKey('1111');

echo '<pre>';
print_r(Tree::getTree());
echo '</pre>';
```

Out:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 12400
                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 12430
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1111
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 233
                        )

                )

            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2010
                    [1] => 2011
                )

        )

)
```

Is this what You needed?

Comment: I need it to stop at the first zero. The zeroes are just place-fillers and will always be at the end of the string.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm trying to do. It seems to be wiping out the prior tree nodes. For example, ID 12400 is the parent of ID 12430, so I'm trying to set the nodes like this:
$tree[1][2][4]['id'] = '12400';
$tree[1][2][4][3]['id'] = '12430';

Comment: @gr8dane All right, then. Here's updated version. This time, with OOP PHP. I hope that's what u needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is variable in this, but based on the question this should work using a reference to build the array.  Somebody will post a recursive one:

```
function addKeys($id) {
    $result = array();
    $temp =& $result;

    foreach(str_split($id) as $key) {
        if($key != 0) {
            $temp =& $temp[$key];
        }
    }
    $temp['id'] = $id;

    return $result;
}

$id = '12430';    
$tree = addKeys($id);    
print_r($tree);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm trying to do. It seems to be wiping out the prior tree nodes. For example, ID 12400 is the parent of ID 12430, so I'm trying to set the nodes like this: $tree[1][2][4]['id'] = '12400'; $tree[1][2][4][3]['id'] = '12430';

Comment: That would have been pertinent info to include in the question don't you think?

Comment: Take another look at the second sentence of my question. It's there, just not in as much detail. I guess I tend more towards being succinct than verbose. Apparently not a virtue, in this case.